# Problem using this site

Tags: discussion

I'm just about positive that the computer I have now is not compatible with Lynx and therefore there are no solutions that will work to get Ubuntu 20.04 to work properly with it.
So how do I delete the question I asked about getting my printer to work.
The solution is to get a new computer.
The other question I have is, how do I follow my own question, so that when people respond, I'll know?

Comment: Please go on and ask the actual question. Check this site every few hours to see if you have any notification (if we post a comment/answer).

Comment: "how do I follow my own question, so that when people respond, I'll know" — that happens automatically, and is always the case. You will get notifications if people answer your question. If you do not visit this site for a few days, it can even send you an e-mail reminder that you have pending notifications.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to delete your question and, in fact, please don't! Questions asked here can help thousands or even millions of other users, they are not just for you. So even if you are no longer interested, someone else might be. Then, if a question gets no upvotes and no answers after a period of time, it will be deleted anyway by the system. So there is no need for you to take any action at all.

As for being notified of an answer, that is how the system works by default. If anyone answers, you will get a notification and (depending on your settings) an email as well.